# Getting Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Here Is My Code Where I'm Making Request A URL Using HttpWebRequest And Getting Response From HttpWebResponse. But httpwebresponse object throws an exception that is Internal Server Error!

```
url="http://www.google.com/"

Uri urlCheck = new Uri(url);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
request.Timeout = 5000000;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();    //Here Getting The Exception..
receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
strmRead = new StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);
result = strmRead.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Try debugging the service. The service is throwing an exception, the client code might be ok.

Comment: @Emo: thank u sir, but which service and can u give any example... or how debug the service???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site is crashing if the client doesn't support cookies. So you could enable support for cookies on the client by setting a CookieContainer:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var url = "http://links.casemakerlegal.com/states/MS/books/Case_Law/results?search[Cite]=77%20So.3d%201094";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Internal Server Error" means exactly that, an internal error on the server you are calling.

This might be a temporary problem on the server that is nothing to do with you, or it might be that the server doesn't like the data you are passing to it. Check the following:

- Is `77%20So.3d%201094` a valid search value?
- Are you supposed to send an API key along with the request?
- Are you supposed to authenticate yourself, e.g. with an HTTP username/password digest, or X509 certificate?

Comment: Actually sir, This Link Work Properly When I Manually Browse It In Mozilla FireFox.....what is API key??